# What is the Correct Flow for a JavaScript Application Pipeline with Buildtime Variables?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-pipelines, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

Consider the following development flow for a frontend JavaScript application:

[image: Development Flow]

Whilst there are endless ways to design a `development`->`staging`->`production` pipeline, the above is fairly standard right?

Given this, why is it that pipeline providers such as Bitbucket and Azure do not allow Environment dependant variables for the `build` step?

Like most JavaScript applications, our application is specifically built for the environment that it will be run in e.g. `development`, `staging`, and `production`. Each environment has their own uniquely defined set of variables, for example; `APP_URL` sets the URL that the application will be accessible under.

The environment variables are specifically read during the build process of the application i.e. they are *buildtime* variables, not *runtime* variables.

Is there a reason why these providers do not support different environment variables for the `build` step? This seems like such an obvious thing which makes me think that actually, our entire pipeline flow is incorrect and it is us that is doing this wrong... Can any suggest a way to overcome this issue? Ideally without setting these variables within the `xyz-pipelines.yml` as the whole purpose of these variables is to keep them out of the repository...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DevOps, it is expected you get an artifact in Build pipeline and then release that artifact into environments using a **Release** workflow.

You could try to build the frontend JavaScript application in the [Release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops), in Release pipeline, which can get artifacts from continuous integration systems such as Azure Pipelines, Jenkins, or TeamCity. You might also use version control systems such as Git or TFVC to store your artifacts. More details, please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#sources

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cece. So are you saying that Azure Pipelines is simply not suited to building and deploying JavaScript applications? On the basis that most JavaScript applications use `buildtime` variables for the environment in which they are going to be run... Running a build within the 'Release' pipeline seems like a suitable 'dirty' fix, but unless Azure offers environment variables specifically for each release `environment` that it is deploying to, the problem still persists... Just to point out, this is offered by BitBucket (my usual provider), and pretty much all others...

Comment: To give an example of what I mean; within our JavaScript application, we have a configuration variable called APP_URL. This value is set based on the environment that the application is run in. As the application is compiled with node (webpack), the variable is set as an environment variable, and is therefore read at buildtime. This is fairly common practice... Building the package twice is a solution but it simply doesn't seem logically correct. The only reasonably 'clean' solution I can see is by setting specific variables dependant on the branch that is being committed

Comment: You can use **Build** Pipeline to build and deploy applications, but you may need to create pipelines for each branch with specific variables. But in **Release** Pipeline, you can fully automate the testing and delivery of your software in `multiple stages` all the way to production: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops. You define and manage variables in the Variables tab of a release pipeline. In the Pipeline Variables page, open the Scope drop-down list and select the required stage.

Comment: Thank you Cece, I am aware of the release variables and how Release's work, I am just hesitant to place the building of my application into the Release stage as it defeats the point of the Build pipeline (aside from running tests). I'll accept this as the answer as it doesn't seem that what we are trying to achieve is possible in the way that we want to achieve it :-D